# Problem with email validation in Opera and Chrome

Tags: javascript, validation, email, google-chrome, opera

I use simple js email validation like:

```
 function validation(email) {
     var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
     return reg.test(email);
 }


 function check(){
   if ($("#subemail").hasClass("bad")) {
       var subemail = $("#subemail").val();
       if((subemail!=0)&&validation(subemail)) {
          $("#subemail").css('background','transparent').css('color','#3b3b3b');
          $('.arrow').css('visibility','hidden');
       }
       else { 
          $("#subemail").css('background','url(img/red.png)').css('color','white');
          $('.arrow').css('visibility','visible');
       }
    }
 }
```

everything works fine with Firefox but while doing it in Chrome or Opera it always return false

Comment: Prepare to get molested for using such a crappy test expression. :)

Comment: On behalf of everyone everywhere, I beg of you not to use that regular expression to validate e-mail addresses. It counts tons of valid addresses as invalid. Most obviously, it doesn't allow `+` in the username portion.

Comment: This makes good reading for anyone even thinking about validating e-mail addresses:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Comment: That regex works fine (well, it matches what it matches, which is of course not at all the set of valid email addresses, but that's a separate point) in Chrome.

Comment: Works in both Chrome and Opera here. At least for my e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

In this test:

```
if((subemail!=0)&&validation(subemail)) {
```

What is it that you mean by checking the email candidate string against 0?  Did you mean:

```
if ((subemail != '') && validation(subemail)) {
```

perhaps?  (The test is redundant anyway, as your regex insists on non-empty strings.)